# Need VBA Code to removing Dot (.) from the amount and it should display number with length of 6 digits

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to the Excel VBA. I have a request from my customer to give them the amounts of each invoice without dot (.) and should be 6 digits in length. There are around 3000+ invoices per day and doing it in the excel using excel formulas is time consuming.

I have a multiline text box (Textbox1) in which I will be feeding in the amounts and a button (cmdRun) which when clicked should give me the amounts converted as per below example.
For example, if the amount is 123.45 then they want it as 012345 0r if the amount is 12.30 then it should be 001250. So basically 4 digits before decimal(if less than 4 then should add 0's before the numbers) and 2 digits after the decimal.

Comment: Multiply by 100 and format to six digits.  Please show what have you tried.  Where have you run into problems?  Might be useful for you to read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this into a seperate module

```
Function sixdigits(amount) As String

Dim strAmount As String

strAmount = Replace(Left(amount, 6), ".", "") ' use replace and left to create a string of 6 characters
Do Until Len(strAmount) >= 6 ' loop until 6+
    strAmount = "0" & strAmount
Loop: sixdigits = strAmount

End Function
```

---

then in your code, where you have the amount from the customer, change the line to:

```
customerAmount = sixdigits(customerAmount)
```

one thing to note is that the amount value is given in a string not a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Format` for this:

```
TextAmount = Format(Amount * 100, String(6, "0"))
```